# Rails query with Countries gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, countries

I have a model: `Car`. Each car belongs to a `Museum` and each museum is in a particular country. The country is stored as a two-character country code.

I then use the `Countries` gem to look up all the details of a country using that alpha2 code.

What I am trying to do is pull out of the database Cars from a particular continent. The `Countries` gem has details of which continent a country is a part of but i'm getting stuck at how to get all the cars from a particular continent.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: I believe you will have to find_all_countries_by_region and you will get a list of countries, then you will have to find all museum of that country and then all cars. If that countries gem have all that info stored in a SQL database, then you can join tables and do just one sql.

Comment: Ok, Countries stores all it's data locally in yaml files which is why I was getting confused as I couldn't just perform a join. I'll have a go.

Comment: so it will have to be like I was thinking, you will get an array of countries as strings, then you create your activerecord query with that info

Answer (score 4):

Supposing that **Car** `belongs_to :museum` and **Museum** has a column named `country` I would solve this problem in a following way:

1. Get all alpha2 country codes for a given continent:

   country_codes = ISO3166::Country.find_all_countries_by_continent('Europe').map(&:alpha2)
2. Load cars with AR query:

   cars = Car.includes(:museum).where(musems: { country: country_codes })